# Add member functions and member variables based on template argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae, template-specialization

I have a family of functions `{f_n}` where `f_0` is continuous, `f_1` is continuously differentiable, $f_{n} \in C^{n}[a,b]$ so on. I have a C++ class which gives a numerical evaluation of `f_n` via a lookup table on a vector `v`

```cpp
template<int n, typename Real=double>
class f
{
public:
    f() { /* initialize v */ }

    Real operator()(Real x) { /* find appropriate index for x, and interpolate */}

private:
    std::vector<Real> v;
};
```

However, if `f` is differentiable (`n >= 1`), I want to add a member function:

```cpp
template<int n, typename Real=double>
class f
{
public:
    f() { /* initialize v and dv */ }

    Real operator()(Real x) { /* find appropriate index for x, and interpolate on v */}

    Real prime(Real x) { /* find appropriate index for x, and interpolate on dv */}

private:
    std::vector<Real> v;
    std::vector<Real> dv;
};
```

I would also like to add a second derivative member for n >= 2, so on.
Can this be done in a single class? (C++17 syntax is acceptable for me.)

Comment: how do you inspect `n` to be larger or equal to `1`? Is this supposed to be a non type template parameter?

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: My bad, typo. Should've been `int n`.

Comment: _"Can this be done in a single class?"_ Well, no. You have a different class for each pair of template parameters. So inherently more than a single class. Did you mean a single (template) declaration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For each `n > 0`, we add a new member function taking that value as an argument that inherits from the next level down:

```
template<int n, typename Real=double>
class f
    : public f<n-1, Real>
{
public:
    f() { /* initialize dv */ }

    using f<n-1, Real>::prime;
    Real prime(Real x, integral_constant<int, n>) { 
        /* find appropriate index for x, and interpolate on dv */
    }

protected:
    std::vector<Real> dv;
};
```

Where the base version adds the `operator()`:

```
template<typename Real=double>
class f<0, Real>
{
public:
    f() { /* initialize v */ }

    Real operator()(Real x) { /* find appropriate index for x, and interpolate */}
    Real prime(Real x) { return (*this)(x); }

protected:
    std::vector<Real> v;
};
```

This means that the first derivative calls `prime(x, integral_constant<int, 1>{})`, the second derivative calls `prime(x, integral_constant<int, 2>{})`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply have a template member function and a static_assert that ensures you are not taking a derivative that is not supported by your class. Eg:

```
template <int n, /* other stuff */>
class f
{
  /* Other stuff not shown */
  template <int p>
  Real prime(Real x)
  {
    static_assert(p <= n, "unsupported derivative");
    /* do whatever you need to to implement the pth derivative */
  }
};
```

Thus an object of type f<1> will support prime<1>() but not prime<2>(), etc. If you accidentally call prime<3> on an object of type f<1> the compiler will call you out on it. Up to you whether you want to think of `prime<0>` as identical to `operator ()` or change your static_assert to include a check for `p > 0`.